What is the korean word for the garlic-like herb known as "asafoetida" or "hing"?
There is an herb with a flavor similar to garlic and the name in Latin is asafoetida
What is the korean word in 한글 for this herb?



Language
Name




Afrikaans
duiwelsdrek


Arabic
ḥiltīt


Assamese
hiṅ (হিং)


Bengali
hiṅ (হিং)


Burmese
shein-kho (ရှိန်းခို)


Danish
dyvelsdræk


Dutch
duivelsdrek


English
Devil's dung


Farsi
Anghoze


Finnish
pirunpaskapirunpihka


French
merde du Diable


German
Teufelsdreck


Gujarati
hīṅg (હિંગ)


Hebrew
chiltit (חלתית‎)


Hebrew
chitt


Hindi
hīṅg (हींग)


Kannada
ingu (ಇಂಗು)


Kashmiri
yang’eh (ینگہہ‎)


Kashubian
czarcé łajno


Malayalam
kāyaṃ (കായം)raamadom


Marathi
hinga (हिंग)


Meitei
hing (ꯍꯤꯉꯒ)


Nepali
hing (हिङ)


Norwegian
dyvelsdrek


Odia
henguହେଙ୍ଗୁ)


Pashto
hënjâṇa  هنجاڼه‎


Polish
czarcie łajno


Spanish
estiércol del diablo


Swedish
dyvelsträck


Tamil
perunkayamபெருங்காயம்


Telugu
inguvaఇంగువ)


Turkish
Şeytan bokuŞeytan otuŞeytan tersi


Urdu
hīṅgہینگ




That's 아위 but it's not that often used in Korean. You can check the Korean dictionary item for that here: https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/c6c32cf5ea6743d0ad601d1c12312bec

Although there is a hanja-eo, 아위 (阿魏), for asafoetida / hing, due to its use in traditional Chinese and Korean medicine, it is not well known as a spice in early 21st-century South Korea. Nonetheless, 아위 is the main translation, and it currently looks like it is ahead of any Hindi- or Latin-based loanword.
